# Fast search for specific child in non binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, lookup-tables

I have a non binary tree, each node in the tree has many children let us say 10000 , and the node has a list of pairs `<key,pointer>` for children. I search for a specific children by its key, so when I find the key then go to the pointer to reach that children. my question is that, is there any way to search the key faster? because I search the list sequentially.

Comment: Is this an on-disk structure?

Comment: Yes, it is on-disk structure.

Comment: @AboAliAlmusawi can you post an example as well, I guess instead of keeping a list of pairs <key, pointer> you can imagine this as a graph and you can then just do dfs on this graph and you will find the node which you want to search.

Comment: there is a  list of pairs <key,pointer> inside each node in the tree, so its hard to build a graph inside each node of the tree. I thought of this also, but it is a little bit complicated . Thanks any way.